# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].normalizeSpace()

Tags: apex

I have written a class in my sandbox and when i try to push the code into prodn i get this error.

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].normalizeSpace()

Both prodn and sandbox uses api ver 25.0. Any idea on why this error when moving the code to prodn.

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < lallowedStates.size(); i++)
 {
    lallowedStates[i] = lallowedStates[i].normalizeSpace();
    sAllowedStates.add(lallowedStates[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Winter13/New+String+Methods

The second last entry is the normalizeSpace method. So this will be available with the winter 13 (v26) release.

Won't work until then.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that method part of the v26 (winter 13) new string methods?  If so, it won't run on v25.  If you're not on v26 yet, you will be soon.

I'm surprise it works on a v25 sandbox org.

Comment: the sandbox is moved to win13 but the class is saved in api 25. I would still assume that it should not work.