# Remove whitespaces in a string

Tags: apex

This is an extension of my earlier  [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/method-does-not-exist-or-incorrect-signature-string-normalizespace) where i was using normalizeSpace(). But since this available only from api 26. How do we remove the whitespaces for earlier versions

Comment: do you want to remove all whitespace or only leading and trailing whitespaces?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If going back to basics I would suggest using the trim() function followed by a regex replacement using replaceAll() that matches instances of the space characters i.e. `(\\s+)` and replaces them with a single space.

Example:

```
String str = ' how is   the weather today ';

str = str.trim();

str = str.replaceAll('(\\s+)', ' ');

return str;
```